# How to fix access permissions for new partition

Tags: permissions, root

New Ubuntu installation on single user system.

Created partition for data.  Not accessible.  Permissions says, owner is "root."

"You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions."

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you use `sudo`, and please run `lsblk -i` and post the results.

Comment: Again who owns the mount point?

Answer (score 3):

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/partition`

`$USER` will automatically change to the current active user.

`-R` means that it will operate on files and directories recursively.

Comment: `/path/to/partition` is something like `/dev/sde1`?  Or like `/media/username/mountpoint`?